# Why is my picture stretched on mobile?

Tags: image, css

Here is the version in firefox development:

[image]

And here is the screencopy in real mobile :

[image]

(Notice that the animated gif above the girl's picture  is fine)

Here is the css :

```
    .img_mobile {
        margin:auto;
        width: 100%; 
        max-width: 100%; 
        height: auto;
    }

#conteneur {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

And here is part of HTML :

```
<div class="img_mobile" id="conteneur">
        <img src="{% static 'img/home/img-mobile-01.jpg'  %}?{{ git_last_commit }}" alt="">
        <img src="{% static 'img/home/animation-image-1.gif'  %}?{{ git_last_commit }}" alt="" style="position:absolute; mix-blend-mode: screen;">
    </div>
```

2 questions :

1. What should I do to resolve this issue?
2. How can I see this mistake in development?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you post some more code? perhaps some html.

Comment: I have updated the original post with more information

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.img_mobile {
    margin:auto;
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fand the solution :

class="img_mobile" should be inside the img tag

But I am still wondering why this mistake can't be check through the firefrox developper tools... so if anyone has an idea about how to test mobile page...